# Print form with value without submitting form in php

Tags: php, forms

I am working with PHP. where I want to print a form with `Print` button. 
My Code:

```
<div id="print-content">
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="authform">
    <div>   
        Business Name:
        <input type="text" name="business_name" id="business_name" required> 
    </div>
</form>
</div>
```

But when I click on print button it will show blank form in print window.
I want to show input field value also(without submiting or reloading page). what is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: javascript ... jquery could be your friend...btw what is a *Print* button?

Comment: use `onclick` function of jquery in which you can write your code for displaying the text

Comment: there is no php here. If it isn't relevant or with relevant code, it needs to be removed.

Comment: *"But when I click on print button it will show blank form in print window."* - There is no "print" button here. Your question is unclear. - *"I want to show input field value also(without submiting or reloading page)."* A: Use ajax.

Comment: <input type="button" onclick="printDiv('print-content')" value="Print">     this is the code for print button. I added it after last </div>

Comment: How can I do it using Javascript??